# Which is the best encryption and decryption algorithm in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanna very good encryption and decryption algorithm in c#?.

I googled Some page,.. I got one,..

```
 private string base64Encode(string sData)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] encData_byte = new byte[sData.Length];
                encData_byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sData);
                string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(encData_byte);            
                return encodedData;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error in base64Encode" + ex.Message);
            }
        }

  public string base64Decode(string sData)
        {
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            System.Text.Decoder utf8Decode = encoder.GetDecoder();
            byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(sData);
            int charCount = utf8Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);
            char[] decoded_char = new char[charCount];
            utf8Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length, decoded_char, 0);
            string result = new String(decoded_char);
            return result;
        }
```

Is it good?. else suggest a good one.

thanks in advance!.

Comment: Base64 is *not* encryption.

Comment: Best decryption algorithm is the one that matches the encryption one.

Comment: I want to encrypt and decrypt my userId and password!. Can any one suggest good good encryption and decryption algorithm?

Comment: please try to ask it with specifications next time.

Comment: @Sagatharan, re-ask that question giving lots of context, be sure to explain why you are not using the facilities built into the OS.

Comment: Can any one suggest good good encryption and decryption algorithm? is it ok?.

Comment: is any facilities into the OS have encryption and decryption things?.

Comment: 4 down vote and 1 up vote????????? what happen???????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First encoding is not encryption.

The choice of encryption algorithm will depend on the requirements of solution. There is no abstract best.

You must consider the level of protection you require, the time you have to perform the operation and how you will transmit the key.

Comment: Thank u!. I am very clear now!.